# Como dar restart em uma Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Quero dar um restart na minha `activity` sem ajuda de botões, quero que reinicie automaticamente dentro de um tempo. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para reiniciar uma `Activity` você pode utilizar o método [recreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29), disponível a partir da API 11.

> Faz essa Activity ser recriada com uma nova instância. Isso resulta no mesmo fluxo quando a Activity é criada devido a uma mudança de configuração -- a instância atual irá percorrer seu ciclo de vida até onDestroy(), e uma nova instância irá ser criada depois.

Answer (score 1):

Completando a resposta de Zulian, você pode colocar esse código na criação da Activity:

```
new CountDownTimer(RESTART_TIME, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

    public void onFinish() {
        recreate();
    }
}.start();
```